# Jquery Datatables - unable to load ajax response into table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatable, datatables

Following is my js

```
         $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                 url: url + 'project/get_project_list',
                 method:'post',
                 dataType:'xml',
                 success:function(data){
                    $('#datatable').dataTable({
                        data:data,
                        columns:[

                        {
                            "data" : "projectName"
                        },
                        { 
                            data : "projectDescription"
                        },

                        ]

                    });
                 }

            });
         });
          $('#datatable').DataTable();


    </script>

<div class="panel-wrapper">

<form id="form1">
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>  
    </table>
  </form>
            </div>
```

My response is as follows

```
 <projectList>
 <exceptionId>0</exceptionId>
 <id>0</id>
 <isException>false</isException>
 <offExptionid>0</offExptionid>
 <listException>false</listException>
 <listExceptionId>0</listExceptionId>
 <listSize>0</listSize>
 <nextPage>false</nextPage>
 <pageNumber>0</pageNumber>
 <projectBOs>
   <exceptionId>0</exceptionId>
 <id>0</id>
 <isException>false</isException>
 <offExptionid>0</offExptionid>
 <projectDescription></projectDescription>
 <projectId>5</projectId>
 <projectName>Bmw</projectName>
 </projectBOs>
 <projectBOs>
 <exceptionId>0</exceptionId>
  <id>0</id>
 <isException>false</isException>
 <offExptionid>0</offExptionid>
 <projectDescription>Toyota</projectDescription>
 <projectId>4</projectId>
 <projectName>Toyota global</projectName>
 </projectBOs>
 <projectBOs>
```

Kindly help how could i bind projectname and projectdescription to the table
.currently it says no data available in table.  i have no idea in using datatables

Comment: You should check the parsed XML data that is made available. It might not be in the format that is accepted by data tables.

Comment: You need to transform the XML to JSON. DataTables only accepts Javascript objects or HTML as data sources.

Comment: can u provide me a working sample ,since i am new to this kind of grids

Answer (score 0):

you may try JSON type data..

```
dataType:'JSON',
```

and pass two dimentional data

```
success:function(data){} //data should be two dimentional
```

Comment: You must be load data in html first then load datatables from html data.
Like :
success: function(data){
    $("#load_data").html(data);
    $('#table_id').DataTable(}););

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var oTable = $('#tableId').dataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "ajax": {
         "url": "verify",
         "dataSrc": "",
         "type": "GET"
      },

      "columns": [
            { "data": "Emp_id"},
            { "data": "Emp_Name" },
            { "data": "Emp_PAN" },
            { "data": "Emp_Email" },
            { "data": "Emp_Address"}
      ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here "verify" is file where i get data from the DB and then convert into JSON and pass using ajax.